# Mule - make Global Elements more global

Tags: mule, mule-studio

In mule I have many applications running on the same container that access a jdbc connector with the same connection string/user/password set.

Of course any app has configured the same global connector in its xml configuration file, so there is code duplication.

Is there a way to define only once per container the connection and access it from any app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this: have one app create the datasource and store it in JNDI and have the other apps pick it up from JNDI.

Since there is no strong guarantee of app start ordering, it's possible that one app that needs the JNDI datasource would start too soon. You would need to configure Spring to be able to perform the JNDI lookup again in case of failure and configure a threaded retry policy on the Mule JDBC connector.

Also you will need to install the datasource and database JARs in lib/user so all apps could use them.

Comment: ah yes that is more optimal for sure!

Comment: Thank you David. Can you give me some code to store datasource in jndi   please?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a spring bean for your JDBC connector in xml some where in your system and have all your applications load it in your apps:

```
   <spring:import resource="JDBC-beans.xml" />
```

and the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

   <!-- Initialization for data source -->
   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST"/>
      <property name="username" value="root"/>
      <property name="password" value="password"/>
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: But that will not load the datasource once per container, but instead once per application, which I think is what the OP wants to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this kind of problem using a Domain project, where I inserted all database configurations that have been used by other projects.